# How do I query a model using named parameters in CakePHP?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp

```
url: /contents/view/chapter:models/section:associations

class ContentsController extends AppController {
     function view() {
          $this->params['named'];
     }
}
```

For example, I have the url and controller above and the goal is to use the key/value information from the url to query a database. How would I create a model to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the passedArgs array:

url: /contents/view/chapter:models/section:associations

```
class ContentsController extends AppController {
         function view() {
              $foo = $this->Foo->find(
                  array('chapter'=>$this->passedArgs['chapter'],
                        'section'=>$this->passedArgs['section']));
         }
    }
```

This is available as a part of Cake 1.2, or with the following additions:

[Cake PHP - Passing Named Parameters](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/passing-named-parameters)

Comment: Yes.  You could just use the Contents model, assuming your db name and all that is the same.  My question is this: is there any different between Controller::passedArgs[index] and Controller::params['named'][index]?

Comment: No, I don't believe there is.  I'm just lazy and prefer using passedArgs